# ¿Cómo reubicar el cursor entre un archivo .xlsb con python?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy tratando de leer una archivo .xlsb para convertirlo en dataframe para lo cual estoy usando pandas, pero tengo el siguiente inconveniente: los archivos vienen en formato .xlsb ya logre leerlos pero algunos formatos tienen el cursor ubicado al final del archivo y por eso cuando lo leo desde python mi dataframe queda vacio, intente reubicar el cursor con el método seek de del modulo io pero no funciona.

```
file_path = "C:\Luis\ETL\extract\Informe de Ventas\Informe Diario Ventas 5-01-2021.xlsb"

file_xlsb = open(file_path, "r")
file_xlsb.seek(0)
file_xlsb.close()

df = pd.read_excel(file_path,engine='pyxlsb')
df
```

Comment: El cursor de lectura de archivo no está "guardado" en el archivo. Es un concepto usado por el programa que lo abre para leer. En el momento que se abre, estará al principio, por lo que el `seek(0)` es irrelevante. Si obtienes un datagrama vacío tiene que deberse a otra cosa. ¿Obtienes algún mensaje de error durante la lectura? Ten en cuenta que la propia documentación de pyxlsb te dice que la librería es _extremadamente limitada_

Comment: Yo te recomendaría abrir el xlsb con Excel y volver a guardarlo como xlsx para evitar problemas

Comment: si ya realice otra prueba y si tienes razón sobre el cursor. Lo que hice fue abrir el archivo y guardarlo sin cambiar la extensión y de esta forma si funcionó el código. Por otra parte no quiero realizar esta tarea de forma manual ya que son muchos archivos extraídos desde un correo electrónico.

Answer (score 0):

Estaba equivocado en cuanto a la ubicación del cursor, encontré la forma de leer el dataframe para que no me saliera vacio no se porque ocurre esto pero tengo que abrir el archivo con extensión .xlsb y volver a guardarlo y luego si proceder a leerlo con pandas; realice un código que me sirve aunque no es muy elegante porque hace eso mismo utiliza la libreria win32 para abrir el archivo y volver a guardarlo usando excel.

```
import pyxlsb
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

cliente = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

def main():

    ruta = "C:\Luis\ETL\extract\Informe de Ventas\Informe Diario Ventas 4-01-2021.xlsb"    

    cliente.Application.DisplayAlerts=False
    s = cliente.Workbooks.Open(ruta)
    s.SaveAs(ruta)
    s.Close
    
    df = pd.read_excel(ruta,engine='pyxlsb')
    print(df)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```